# How can I get back to the first column again after iterating over all the columns of a Pandas dataframe from an increased location?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

In the code below I'm iterating over the columns of a Pandas dataframe. For each column I did some operations. After doing operations on the last column I want to get back to the first column of the dataframe and again iterate over each column one by one from an increased location of j+512. How can I do that?

```
for column in df:
    j=0
    col_one_list = df[column].tolist()
    mav1 = mav(col_one_list[j:j+256])
    mav2 = mav(col_one_list[j+256:j+256+256])
```

Comment: do another for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loop_time = 3
j = 0
for i in range(loop_time):
    for column in df:
        col_one_list = df[column].tolist()
        mav1 = mav(col_one_list[j:j+256])
        mav2 = mav(col_one_list[j+256:j+256+256])
    
    j+=512
```